# Multiple exception handlers for the same Exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a code for a function which is called inside another function.(Result of refactoring).

So in the called function I have a huge block of try-catch statements as.

```
def Called():
     try:
         #All statements for the function in the try block.
     except A:
         # Exception handler.
     except B:
         # Exception handler.
     except A: 
         # Exception handler.
```

The problem I have is that I need to catch two exceptions of the same type (At different locations in the Called function). Which then are handled by the Calling function.

One way would be to define two try-except blocks within the Called function. But I am not understanding how the Calling function can handle two exceptions of the same type differently.

Comment: This doesn't make sense... _why_ do you need two `catch` blocks for the same exception?

Comment: **two exceptions of the same type**, name some `same type` exceptions?

Comment: You will need to use nested exceptions to do what your after. Personally I would recommend you thinking over your problem and you might find another solution to the problem.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: HTTPException, when I am connecting to the server.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Since I intend to handle both the exceptions of the same type differently.

Comment: and what are the two conditions that you need to handle?

Comment: Can I know the reason for being downvoted?

Comment: @veepsk -- I didn't, but I guess you didn't provide enough information about your problem, to answer it sufficiently.

Answer (score 4):

This won't work as advertised; only the first `except A` clause will ever get executed. What you need is either some logic *inside* the clause to further inspect the exception, or (if the code inside the `try` block permits) several `try`-`except` blocks.

Example of the former approach:

```
try:
    something_that_might_fail()
except A as e:
    if e.is_harmless():
        pass
    elif e.is_something_we_can_handle():
        handle_it()
    else:
        raise    # re-raise in the hope it gets handled further up the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
def Called():
     try:
         #All statements for the function in the try block.
     except A:
         try: 
             do_someting()
         except B:
             try:
                do_somthing_else()
             except:

     except A: 
         # Exception handler.
```