# Python one exception multiple handlers

Tags: python, exception, coding-style, paradigms

I want to do this:

```
try:
    raise A()
except A:
    print 'A'
except (A, B):
    print 'A,B'
```

Which I hoped would print both `A` and `A,B`.

That doesn't work (only the first `except` is executed). It makes sense for the first `except` to swallow the error, in case you want to catch a subclass before it's parent.

But is there another elegant way to get this to work?

I could of course do the following, but that is seemingly redundant code duplication, especially if more than just `A` and `B` are involved:

```
try:
    raise A()
except A:
    print 'A'
    print 'A,B'
except B:
    print 'A,B'
```

(Related to [Multiple exception handlers for the same Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463722/multiple-exception-handlers-for-the-same-exception) but not a duplicate. The usage is different and I want to know how best to handle it with minimal code duplication.)

Comment: @vaultah (why) did you delete your answer?

Comment: I did, because I wasn't happy with it.

Comment: Why do you want to print A, B  when the exception is only related to A?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: With `except (A, B)` the exception could also be related to `B`.

Comment: why not just `catch (exceptions...) as e` and print e.whatever

Comment: Both the `print` and the `raise A()` are meant as examples; it could be other code.

Comment: @Mark, you can subclass and do whatever you want in the  print e.whatever part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather common to catch possible exceptions and get exception type from the instance later:

```
try:
    raise A()
except (A, B) as e:
    if isinstance(e, A):
        print('A')
    print('A', 'B')
```

Another option is to inherit one class from another e.g.

```
class B(Exception):
    def do(self):
        print('A', 'B')

class A(B, Exception):
    def do(self):
        print('A')
        super().do()
```

Then

```
try:
    raise B()
except (A, B) as e:
    e.do()
```

will print `A B`, and

```
try:
    raise A()
except (A, B) as e:
    e.do()
```

will print `A` and `A B`.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this style but it seems this is the closest way possible

Comment: @Mark see the update, I added another possible option

Comment: Could be useful, but I think often the error handling code isn't related enough to the error object to make it a method. Still, occasionally useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nested try-except-blocks:

```
try:
    try:
        raise A()
    except A:
        print 'A'
        raise
except (A, B):
    print 'A,B'
```